# Moq object always returns null , why?

Tags: c#, moq

I make the next moq call:

```
var mock = new Mock<IPagoService>();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetCodigoAutorizacion(Guid.NewGuid())).Returns("e");
string p = mock.Object.GetCodigoAutorizacion(Guid.NewGuid());
```

Why is the variable `p` null?

Comment: You set it up with one Guid but call it with another because `Guid.NewGuid()` is going to create a new Guid each time you call it.

Answer (score 4):

When you have:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetCodigoAutorizacion("A")).Returns("B");
```

You will tell, if invoked with "A", then return "B". Note, If invoked with something else, e.g, "C", it returns the default value of the type.

So you need, if invoked with **any** then GUID returns "e" - you could use `It.IsAny<T>()`.

So for this case:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetCodigoAutorizacion(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns("e");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setup is using one `Guid` and the call another. Since the setup and the call do not match it returns the default.  Instead assign the `Guid` to a variable and use that.

```
var mock = new Mock<IPagoService>();
var id = Guid.NewGuid();
mock.Setup(m => m.GetCodigoAutorizacion(id)).Returns("e");
string p = mock.Object.GetCodigoAutorizacion(id);
```

If you need to handle any `Guid` then do this instead

```
mock.Setup(m => m.GetCodigoAutorizacion(It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns("e");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Guid.NewGuid()` value will be different each time so it doesn’t satisfy your setup condition.

You can use `Guid.Empty` or some constant value to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the two `Guid.NewGuid()` calls generate two different guid values, and so when you're calling the mockup you're passing and entirely new guid from the one that was set up. You can either save the initial guid value and reuse it, or if you don't mind what guid it is you can use:
`It.IsAny<Guid>()` in the setup to accept any guid.